# KQL- make list for numeric values only

Tags: kql

I'm new at QKL and got stuck doing some complex aggregations.
I have a dataset with two columns - one column named key and one value.
I want to make list of all the **numeric** values with the same key , but keep non-numeric value as seperate .

For example if my dataset looks like this

| key | value |
| --- | --- |
| location | "CA" |
| location | "LA" |
| code | "2" |
| code | "3" |
| IP | "192.143.204.19" |

Meaning I want to get the following table

| key | value |
| --- | --- |
| location | "CA" |
| location | "LA" |
| code | ["2","3"] |
| IP | "192.143.204.19" |

`summarize vals=make_set(val) by key` won't work because it will combine "LA" and "CA" and when trying to do `make_set_if` I got empty lists in the non-numeric values.

Has anyone have an idea how to solve it ?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try this (handling both cases separately, then `union`ing the results):

```
let T = datatable(key:string, value:string)
[
    "location", "CA",
    "location", "LA",
    "code", "2",
    "code", "3",
    "IP",   "192.143.204.19",
]
| extend long_value = tolong(value)
;
T
| where isnull(long_value)
| union (
    T
    | where isnotnull(long_value)
    | summarize value = tostring(make_list(long_value)) by key
)
| project key, value
```

| key | value |
| --- | --- |
| location | CA |
| location | LA |
| IP | 192.143.204.19 |
| code | [2,3] |